# Como capturar o nome de um arquivo $_FILE e imprimir num echo

Tags: php

```
<form action="upload2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="arquivo[]" multiple="multiple"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar"/>
```

upload2.php

```
<?php
$diretorio = "img/";

if(!is_dir($diretorio)){
echo "pasta $diretorio não existe";
}else{
$arquivo =isset($_FILES['arquivo'])?$_FILES['arquivo'] : FALSE;

for($controle = 0; $controle<count($arquivo['name']);$controle++){
$destino = $diretorio."/".$arquivo['name'][$controle];

    if (move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$controle],$destino)){
        echo "upload realizado com sucesso<br><br>";

    }
    else{
        echo "erro ao realizar upload";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `echo $_FILES['arquivo']['name']`?

Comment: pra mim deu esse erro Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\upload_arquivos\upload2.php on line 20

Comment: $destino = $diretorio."/".$arquivo.... `vai gerar img// .....` com duas barras

Comment: echo $arquivo['name'][$controle];

Comment: talvez o erro seja no nome do input `name="arquivo[]"`. É correto usar [] no nome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A questão é que usando `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="upload[]">` o `PHP` vai receber o array assim:

```
$_FILES['upload']['name'][n]
```

Onde `n` é equivalente ao número de arquivos adicionados pelo `<input>`.
Então para imprimir os nomes dos arquivos que foram selecionados, você pode usar um `for()`:

```
$numero_de_arquivos = count($_FILES['upload']['name']); // conta o número de arquivos adicionados
for($i = 0; $i < $numero_de_arquivos; $i++){
    echo $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]; // aqui ele pega o nome de cada arquivo e imprime com o echo
    echo "<br>";
}
```